# How to remove silence from an audio file while leaving a bit of the otherwise deleted portion?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Pardon the title, it's a bit difficult to explain concisely!

I have a bunch of short (1s-4s) recordings of people reading sentences. They were recorded themselves. Often, there is a bit of silence at the beginning or end, and I would like to automate removing that.

As a first pass, I used this command:

```
sox original.mp3 edited.mp3 silence 1 0.1 2% reverse silence 1 0.1 2% reverse
```

The problem is that when people speak, sometimes the very beginning of their speech is quiet and quickly ramps up. This command thus clipped the very beginning of a number of sentences.

So what I would like to do is essentially the same as what the sox command does, but ideally once it detects the boundary, it leaves 50ms before the boundary, in recognition that there may be some quiet but important sounds.

I think that ffmpeg might be a good tool for this, as I don't think sox can be configured like that. I'm tool agnostic. I don't know ffmpeg at all though, so I appreciate any help putting together a command given ffmpeg's rather arcane syntax!

Another nice to have over the aforementioned sox command is for it only to remove silence at the beginning and end (if it exists) -- not from the middle of the recording.

UPDATE: based on time spent with ffmpeg, it looks like I want something like this

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_threshold=0.02:start_silence=0.1:detection=peak,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_threshold=0.02:start_silence=0.1:detection=peak,areverse" output.mp3
```

Oddly, this comes out garbled. I thought that it wasn't reversing properly, but when I try to do something like

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af areverse output.mp3
```

It doesn't work -- I just get the input back. I'm not sure what is going wrong?

If I just do the beginning,

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_threshold=0.02:start_silence=0.1:detection=peak" output.mp3
```

It works fine -- for the beginning. But not sure why the reverse trick is resulting in a garbled output.

UPDATE2: it actually looks like the command works, but it changes the metadata in a way that makes itunes wonky. If I use VLC instead, it works fine.

Comment: DId you see the replies at AskMF?

Comment: I did, but I'm struggling with the 50ms before and after piece, and figured that stack overflow was a more appropriate place to dig for those details, if some kind soul is willing to help :)

Comment: For that, use the start_silence and stop_silence options.

Comment: So I dug more into this and I came up with what I have added to the question...but now it is somehow getting garbled?